# python how many palindromes are in a list of strings

Tags: python

I'm trying to input a sequence of words and count how many palindromes or non-palindromes(unique words) are in the sequence but can't tell what I'm doing wrong. My loop isn't counting the elements of the list and is instead counting the entire list I believe.

```
user_input = input('Enter word sequence:')

string = user_input.split()

temp = [i[::-1] for i in string]

unique = 0
is_palindrome = 0

for i in temp:

   if i in temp == string:
      is_palindrome += 1

   else:
       unique += 1

print('There are', is_palindrome, 'Palindromes, and', unique, 'unique words')
```

if someone could help me I'd appreciate it.

Comment: string is a list so you can't compare an iterable to a list (i to string).

Comment: Why `if i in temp == string:` ? Try remove `in temp` I think it should solve it, unless you have duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You splitted input and reversed every word. You implemented very good so far but below, your implementation is wrong.

```
for i in temp:

   if i in temp == string:
      is_palindrome += 1
```

You are going through in temp but this line of code `if i in temp == string` is not the right implementation because you are comparing `if i in temp` which returns boolean and `string` which is a list. You need to compare `temp` list's indexes and `string` list's indexes if they match or not. if they match they are palindrome. You can implement as follow.

```
for i in range(len(temp)):
    if temp[i] == string[i]:
        palindrome += 1
    else:
        unique += 1
```

Comment: @sunnymuffinz Please mark it as the answer if it has worked

Comment: actually, this doesn't quite work correctly and for some reason only counts 1 palindrome and 1 unique when there are still 3 words

Comment: Could you edit your question for which input it doesn't work. It needs to work because i have explained which lines you implemented as wrong so i have corrected them. Your implementation and my correction together must give right output.

Answer (score 0):

Since reading the words does not seem to be the kernel of the question, let us skip this step and declare explicitly a list of words, then count the number of words, that coincide with the reciprocal:

```
my_words = [ 'abccba', '101101', 'joy', 'bar', 'john', 'anna' ]
print( [ word == word[::-1] for word in my_words ].count(True) )
```